# Where is Preview.app's .savedState?

Tags: macos, preview, resume

Since Mac OS X Lion introduced the Resume feature, where applications save their open windows and document states, compatible applications have stored their window states to disk in the directory `~/Library/Saved Application State`, in directories like `com.apple.finder.savedState`.

However in my `Saved Application State` directory, there is no `com.apple.Preview.savedState`. When I launch Preview.app, it does remember all its open windows and their states, but I cannot find where the state is stored on disk. It does not appear in the usual location. Can you help me find where Preview.app is saving its window states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Finder search for `com.apple.preview` with system files "are included" revealed the location of the file:

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`.

Thanks.